# Can we please be more generous to elementary beginners?

Tags: discussion, deletion

This [question: Given that $\arctan(1/5) + \arctan(1/8) = \arctan(1/p)$, how to find the value of $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3167525/9464) (now deleted again) was originally closed as "off-topic".

Here is the original title:

> Tricky Trig question - Given that arctan(1/5) + arctan(1/8) = arctan(1/p) find the value of P.

And here is the original body of the post:

> I understand that you must use the tan(x+y) rule. And for a start, I let x = tan 1/5 and let y = 1/8. But what happens to arctan(1/p)?

A user [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3167530/9464) and edited the attempt in the post (colors mine):

> I understand that you must use the $\tan(x+y)$ rule. And for a start, I let $\color{red}{x = \arctan 1/5}$ and let $\color{blue}{y = \arctan 1/8}$. But what happens to $\arctan(1/p)$?

I later edited the format of the title and made it to a concise question with a question mark. Also, I edited the body of the post in a slightly more readable way.

> Given that $\arctan(1/5) + \arctan(1/8) = \arctan(1/p)$, how to find the value of $p$?
>
> **Attempt**
>
> I think that one should use the rule for $\tan(x+y)$. And for a start, I let $x = \arctan 1/5$ and let $y = \arctan 1/8$. But what happens to $\arctan(1/p)$? I do not know how to go on.

After the edit, I voted to reopen the question. It was then deleted once by active users in the CRUDE chat room. After it was undeleted by three users (including myself), a user (who voted to delete the post previously) rollbacked the post to the original one and then immediately voted to delete the post again while it is "on-hold". (See the [timelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3167525/revisions) for mentioned activities.)

I refuse such a strong action of deletion to a post like this. The OP did have a well-formulated though elementary mathematical question. True that the original attempt was a mess. However, I think a beginner like this one could certainly have difficulties in articulating his/her own thoughts clearly. For a beginner who is asking this level of questions, if he/she was really able to clearly identify where he/she was stuck, following strictly the "how to ask a good question" guide, then they would be very likely to be able to answer such question on his/her own and have no need to ask a question on MSE at all.

For such beginners, I think we could be little more generous to help since

> Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at **any** level and professionals in related fields.

**Can we please be more generous to elementary beginners?**

---

[Added for responding to criticism in the comment below. Since the response is quite long, and highly related to some points I would like to emphasize, I think it good to write it here.]

> "That has little to do with being elementary."

It does. I am in particular talking about questions asked by "*elementary beginners*". I am *not* talking about "elementary questions" *per se*. There is a huge difference between how an expert/experienced learner asks an elementary question in calculus and how a *beginner* (who is still learning Calculus 101) asks a "routine" homework exercise when such exercise may not sound "routine" to the beginner at all. I am talking about **human beings**. The first sentence in the [Tour site](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) says in particular **people** (studying) at any level, not "question" at *any* level. Moreover, I have clearly stated above that "I think a beginner like this one could certainly have difficulties in articulating his/her own thoughts clearly."

> "Please make sure to include in your reply why =1/8 is due to confusion as opposed to being sloppy. Otherwise, please, explicitly acknowledge that the post was indeed sloppy."

I hate to be rude, but would you PLEASE read my post more carefully before making a misleading judgement?! I clearly wrote that the *question* (the one in the edited title) is clear while OP's original *attempt* was not satisfactory: "The OP did have a well-formulated though elementary mathematical question. True that the original attempt was a mess." Also, I have already explicitly colored the parts that were changed in the second version of the post.

> Again nobody took the time to explain to OP what they could do to avoid common pitfalls on the site.

People can learn things by positive actions. One can learn how one's thoughts/attempts were a mess and likely avoid making similar mistakes in the future by simply reading well-written solutions. Also, reading an edit which articulates clearly a possible attempt is a way to learn. Yes, one might say "how the heck do you know what OP thinks; one should be responsible for him/herself and no one needs to take such burden of teaching." True that we are not mind readers. BUT, there are people who ARE willing to help by positive actions. I do not think such help is so detrimental to MSE that we should eradicate such posts by the strong negative action of deletion.

Comment: The post was very sloppily written. That has little  to do with being elementary. Unfortunately no one explained the problems with the post to OP. As for your meta post, it's generally better to formulate an honest question or to attempt to start an actual discussion rather than to write yet another plea. That the question is elementary really misses the point. Tangentially, some other users advocate for poorly phrased more advanced questions. You see where this is going? Either we do nothing for the quality of the site because everybody has their own set of exceptions or we are more uniform.

Comment: Of course the "either"  above is a false dichotomy, since we could decide on some set of exceptions. But my vote won't be for including carelessly type standard calculus exercises  there. We already have tens not to say hundreds of thousands of those. There is really zero need for more of those as far as the site is concerned.

Comment: Quid of course it has a LOT to do with being elementary. I just can not believe a moderator wrote his or her comment in such a hurry way. Downvote to your comment. You are violating the being nice rule by simply unfairly assuming my attention for posting this question is bad.

Comment: you Yourself consider a question as careless while there are LOT OF PEOPLE only see confusion and simply trying to help.

Comment: Not the first time such rollback downvote close deletion behavior is encouraged. I am so surprises that when such matter is brought out for discussion, a moderator is so hurried to take sides.

Comment: Alright so what is the confusion behind $y=1/8$?

Comment: Again nobody took the time to explain to OP what they could do to avoid common pitfalls on the site. Not you, not the answerer, not all those upvoters. This is not the best way to help. If you ask me, it's a misguided way to help (and that's assuming positive intentions).

Comment: Sorry, I have to be offline now and I will get back to you later and elaborate further my point if you insist it is not clear yet.

Comment: Please make sure to include in your reply why $y=1/8$ is due to confusion as opposed to being sloppy. Otherwise, please, explicitly acknowledge that the post was indeed sloppy.

Comment: I think that this post is just going to be a rehashing of discussions that have been had over and over again over the years... [here's a post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/quick-downvoting-of-ill-formatted-questions-by-new-users) with virtually the same sentiment. From 7 years ago.

Comment: @T.bongers probably the community shares a completely different opinion 7 years ago, since the population was way smaller back then (but I guess one can also easily find similar meta post which is more recent)

Comment: Now undeleted and reopened.

Comment: @Gerry gone again

Comment: @Arctic, yes, deleted by moderator quid, so users can't vote to undelete now. But users can flag for moderator attention, if they think a moderator shouldn't take such action on a question under active discussion on meta.

Comment: "I think that one should use the rule for $\tan(+)$. " clearly indicates an attempt no matter how stupid one thinks this is. While we are still having a discussion, which related to the linked post, the moderator should really not use his/her power to eradicate a post by a *new* user, which significantly violates the spirit in the Code of Conduct. The comment under the deleted post: "This question did not comply with our guidelines for how to ask good questions." is nothing but the moderator's own view.

Comment: This question is probably not the best choice to argue the general principles because it is surely a dupe of many others on the (arc)tan addition formula, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022654/proof-of-an-addition-theorem) for a random example.

Comment: The problem is now I cannot see the timeline and in particular the edit that is involved, so I cannot join the discussion (I am not interested to join anyway so won't flag)

Comment: The questions was in state "deleted" when the meta question was raised. The state prior to the start of the discussion is thus restored. I won't enter a finger-pointing debate on procedures, but it'd be easy enough to turn all those arguments around.

Comment: @quid fyi: in the past some mods have even (temporarily) undeleted questions so that *all* users could view them during meta discussion. This restores transparency - which is important in matter like these.

Comment: @Bill since the post was deleted when the meta post was written OP here made an effort to explain it quite well. I think the  situation is reasonably transparent. If it must be, we can undelete and lock. I'd say though that there is also some merit  in having it deleted. It is not without issue to drag a new user into the spot-light without them having much any influence or understanding what happens to them. It could be argued it would have been better raise without direct  reference to any particular post. However one sees it, the one specific post is hardly  what is at actually at stake.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, but my point was just that that's a particularly early iteration of the same discussion; I seem to remember a "let's not close new users' questions" discussion every few months, with the latest one some time early this year. I strongly doubt that this one is going to produce any new ideas.

Comment: @quid seems to forget that moderators make extremes more moderate, and not more extreme.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee really? There I thought I am trying to get the OP here from their anti-quality-control position back to a more middle of the road position. It's all a matter of perspective. And quite frankly I think I oversee the global situation as well as various side aspects of the situation rather better than most others.

Comment: Have any comments to the question under discussion been deleted? If not then I am disappointed in that neither Jack nor Maria tried to help the asker by explaining to them what was wrong with the question, and what kind of changes are expected. I do see that you both edited it. That's fine and appreciated. But, IMO it would be better to also explain this to the asker. Without such displays of helpfulness this looks like yet another anti-quality-control rant.

Comment: It's not at all anti-quality-control. it's simply they changed the functions stated, Therefore  decreasing the usefulness of answers to a question without knowing of the improper understamding the OP has. That's missed information by the future answerers. rolling back edits just to force deletion, is a crap tactic at best.

Comment: But, I also agree with Bill. This question is essentially a duplicate of many others. After all, basicall it is about knowing the tangents of two angles and then asking what is the tangent of the sum. Therefore I support keeping it deleted. The best way to help new users is to teach them to search the site.

Comment: Jyrki: as I have explained in several comments, I take a *mathematical question* and an *attempt* by OP in a "post" differently. There is nothing wrong with the mathematical question *per se* in OP. It is a well-formulated, unambiguous question. On the other hand, OP's original attempt was a "mess", which is rather common for a beginner, who is not matured mathematically enough yet to articulate his/her own thoughts. But such unsatisfactory attempts do not affect the "question". Hence the question in the title of my post here.

Comment: " After all, basicall(y) it is about knowing the tangents of two angles and then asking what is the tangent of the sum." Most the questions on MSE could be classified on MO as "basically it is about a trivial routine exercise in an undergraduate/graduate course". Such question could be rather nontrivial for a beginner. If MSE does want to welcome all level of mathematical learns, one could/should expect such elementary individuals, who could not yet be even able to identify an abstract duplicate of a question in the first place.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee if it's about the rollback it seems you missed that I did speak out against rollbacks in this thread. Plus, it could get deleted with or without the rollbacks. Incidentally it is deleted in Jack's version. Thus, that's orthogonal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen there is exactly one deleted comment in that thread, which was written long past OP had left (for now). Also it is merely the editor and the answerer coordinating to get the post reopened. It was self-deleted.

Comment: Re your edit, I hate to repeat myself, yet while you did qualify the attempts as a mess,  you also keep saying things like 'which is rather common for a beginner, who is not matured mathematically enough yet to articulate his/her own thoughts' They said they want to substitute "tan x = 1/5" and "y= 1/8". I think they pretty clearly did not want to do that. The asymmetry just makes no sense at all.  Instead they likely simply dropped a "tan" by inadvertence. Now, that's not terrible, but let's not pretend it has much to do with being mathematical mature.

Comment: Thanks @quid. If the asker left, then I guess it's pointless and try to educate them about the site norms. Anyway, the users most keen to keep the question undeleted should take the lead, and educate the asker. I will drop this matter, as they did try to improve the post and used their hard-earned edit privilege!

Comment: I have repeated myself many times that I take "question" and the "attempt" in a post differently and have explained many times my opinion that OP's "attempt" should be treated differently from the question. I have also repeated myself that OP did have a well-formulated mathematical question in his/her post. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) "let's not pretend it has much to do with being mathematical mature. " distorts my arguments in my post: I have never said/assumed OP's attempt shows "mathematical mature" (but I do believe in OP made efforts no matter how silly you think they are) and on the contrary, it is due to the very lack of mathematical maturity that I raise my question in the title of this post.

Comment: @Jack I did not imply that you said or assumed that OP's attempt shows "mathematical maturity" What makes you think I did this? Instead what you seem to do is trying to leverage the assumed *lack of* mathematical maturity to justify and to excuse the shortcomings of parts of the post, in particular, of the attempt. My objection is against the reasoning the question is simple, therefore we need to look past shortcoming of the post. This can make sense, **yet not** when the shortcomings of the post have nothing to do with the mathematical level as it is the case here.

Comment: I just feel that your words *People can learn things by positive actions* really touches my heart @Jack.

Comment: I think I saw Jack place a bounty on a question probably under this same umbrella, but I can't find it now. While I strongly disprove of the practice (I think it is against an established policy, a rule even), I also tacitly tipped my hat. Putting their hard earned rep where there mouth is, is kinda rare. Too rare, if you ask me :-)

Comment: JI do think that this community site should split into subgroups, one for undergraduates, another for post graduates and another for off-topic questions. Lastly, keep this one for the black-belted mathematicians who wish to post unsolveable rigor questions or for those love rigor challenges.

Answer (score 122):

While I am preparing (slowly, due to lots of urgent foreground tasks) a longer post about deletion on math.se, let me quickly suggest a simple guideline:

> **Do not roll back improvements** to a question unless they clearly make it worse or conflict with the question's intent.

This means, in particular, to not roll back clarifications and context (unless the author disagrees with them), LaTeX and formatting fixes.

As usual, please **vote** this post up or down depending on your agreement/disagreement with my guideline.

This is the second time that I am seeing "punitive" rollbacks (someone improves the post, then someone else rolls the improvement back, supposedly because the OP didn't "deserve" to have their question improved). While I understand the reasoning behind them, I think **generating good content for readers is more important than training askers**. This holds doubly so when the "training" is done in a way that is neither instructive nor helpful.

I did cast a delete vote on this specific question, though -- something I rarely do, but found justified in this case because it is literally a numerical example of a known formula.

Comment: Punitive rollbacks are abusive, and I think they should be dealt with directly by the moderators - they're no better than vandalism. But I don't think that necessarily happened here - the first round of editing radically changed the asker's words and basically redid their entire work. A rollback might not be the best way to handle this, but undoing the first edit was good IMHO.

Comment: While I agree with your proposal, this is not really the main point of the question imo. One just shouldn't roll back improvement, whether or not the OP is a newcomer or not.

Comment: I agree with this post. If somebody thinks it should be pointed out that the current version is not due to OP, they can leave a comment saying so (linking to the original version). This should be sufficient. [An exception would be clarifications where an actual choice is made on what the intent was. One should  be very careful with those.]

Comment: My post was also referencing https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982612/how-to-find-sum-k-1n1-fracn-binomnk-1-binom2-nk . But I think it applies here just as well: Maria Mazur's edit (revision 2) fixed a tan/arctan error, and Jack's edit (revision 3) improved the formatting (question in title only -> question in post) and the wording. Both of these are clear-cut improvements if you ask me.

Comment: @darijgrinberg The first one is an improvement *only* because it changes the asker's wrong idea to the answerer's right idea. That's fundamentally altering the question, and is inappropriate.

Comment: I think this is much too strongly said. If a question is ambiguously phrased and someone "improves" it by making one of several possible readings explicit without any input from the OP, then that should be rolled back until the OP speaks up. If a question has an error of notation that gives clues as to what it is the OP fails to understand, and someone "improves" it by fixing the error and making it look like the OP understands this detail perfectly, then that improvement should be rolled back.

Comment: Bongers and Henning, One could say that revision 2 changed the ("messy"/"sloppy") *attempt*, but not the *question* itself. OP did have a well-formulated clear mathematical question: "Given that $\arctan(1/5) + \arctan(1/8) = \arctan(1/p)$, how to find the value of $p$?" There is no typo, no ambiguity at all and revision 3 only changed the format regarding this part. And "I think that one should use the rule for tan(+)" clearly indicates that OP has something in his/her mind. On the other hand, an "attempt" is an attempt, is not a solution, no matter how silly it looks like. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Even matured mathematician could start from a nonsense attempt when doing research. I think it is way too harsh for us to require that every single word in a beginner's attempt should make sense.

Comment: I support this answer. I also want to remind everybody that the asker does not "own" the question. The users with the privilege to edit questions should IMNSHO use it when they want to "rescue" question. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18960/11619) is one earlier related discussion. My rather radical edit got a relatively positive response at that time. Admittedly that may have been partly due to it still being my *moderator honeymoon* with the crowd.

Comment: @Jack 'clearly indicates that OP has something in his/her mind.' Clearly? Maybe they just regurgitated a hint the instructor gave, 'completing' it without much thought. Or operated by analogy to something they saw, again without much thought. Many things are possible. If we wanted to have known we might have asked OP to include the actual formula they have in mind.

Comment: Yes, "Many things are possible." That is exactly why I would rather *believe/assume* OP, who is a new user, indeed had put an effort (no matter how stupid an expert may think) to his/her exercise while he/she was not yet able to articulate his/her own thoughts clearly, which, does not affect the clarity of the mathematical question itself.

Comment: @Jack even then, so what? What is the actual loss for that individual? It is very possible they don't even know (yet) the post disappeared. Who says that they even care? If *you* are frustrated that *your efforts* to edit the post got invalidated (and same for the answerer) then be up-front about this, and don't only talk about supposed injustice or unkindeness inflicted  on a new user. Chances are they don't care all that much. (Tangentially re new, their SO account is old (though small).)

Comment: @Henning Probably you agree, but I want to state that I would judge such things case-by-case. In many a case it is clear to a mathematically mature reader what the question should be, and then I don't have any qualms about such a user making a relatively radical edit. However, I also admit that  even a mature user can misjudge a situation. In addition to that a less mature user may mangle up things easily. I guess you are concerned about something like that?

Comment: "If you are frustrated that your efforts to edit the post got invalidated (and same for the answerer) then be up-front about this, and don't only talk about supposed injustice or unkindeness inflicted on a new user." I could almost assume such words as a personal attack. Considering that an "if" statement is used, in which the assumption is completely pointless, I take it as a false-implies-everything statement. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) On the other hand, what one can see from the timeline is that a user voted to delete the posts *twice* while there are people who hold different opinions have already voted to undelete and reopen the post. Moreover, the strong action of moderator deletion makes your message "This question did not comply with our guidelines for how to ask good questions. Please review these guidelines before asking further questions to avoid future problems. " under the deleted post useless for OP.

Comment: "[T]he strong action of moderator deletion makes your message "This question did not comply with our guidelines for how to ask good questions. Please review these guidelines before asking further questions to avoid future problems. " under the deleted post useless for OP. " How exactly @Jack (Any reason you don't notify me?)

Comment: @quid: Could you please post an answer, so that the community may vote your position both up and down?

Comment: @Kevin I expressed my agreement with this answer early on. What other position should I elaborate on?

Comment: @quid: The deletion which you and Jack are arguing over.

Comment: @Kevin  the appropriateness of and reason for deletion is subject of this post, too.  Further, it does not seem there is much opposition to the deletion of this particular post. It'd look differently if many cared about that post specifically. There is as always some opposition to mod deletions, but since it's a pretty clear cut case it's rather mild. Maybe I'll collect some thoughts, but the deletion of this one post is all things considered pretty minor.

Comment: @quid: I noticed in several comments that you are justifying your approach to deleting this question on the basis of unrelated behavior by the OP. I specifically wanted to downvote *that*, because it strikes me as entirely wrong. Questions should rise or fall on their own merits. But since you have not posted an answer, I cannot cast my vote.

Comment: @Kevin excuse me, but  the entire thread is predicated on the notion that the question should be treated according to a specific set of standards **because the OP is** new, (assumed to be) mathematical not mature, did include some 'attempt'; and maybe some other things. I react to this. The question is of basically no value, so much so that users rather critical of deletions in general are of the opinion there is no point in keeping it or making an example of it. Alright it is possible that you already downvote the question because of this, but if not, I am a bit puzzled what your point is.

Comment: @quid: Very well. I posted an answer instead.

Comment: @T.Bongers just to draw your attention to the preceding comment. Basically this looks like if you don't let me bully you into writing an answer I'll write one to spite you. Maybe that's an uncharitable way to put it, but in essence it's this.

Comment: @quid: I pinged you to let you know of my answer, to give you an opportunity to comment on it, and to downvote it, if you so chose. I did not realize that that would be interpreted as "bullying," for which I apologize.

Comment: "it does not seem there is much opposition to the deletion of this particular post." @quid, the post was undeleted by vote of three users. Two more users joined those three to vote to reopen. As it was redeleted-by-moderator, we can't really know how much more opposition to deletion there might be, but I note that my comment elsewhere on this page, hinting that a moderator ought not take such action, got six upvotes. All in all, it's not clear to me that there isn't much opposition to deletion.

Comment: @Kevin if you would have wanted to make your point you could have made it in an answer. No need to drag me into this, or to go on and on about me in your answer. You searched a confrontation with me and do not even have the sense to actually reply to the points I raise (the edit to your answer essentially invalidates already your entire prior critique).

Comment: @GerryMyerson well, this answer here says that deletion is justified. Check its score. Granted it's not only or even mostly about the deletion. But not much disagreement is voiced. If you have an argument as to why the post should not  be deleted you can present it somewhere and see how much support you get. Ideally make it about the the merits of the post, and not about the fact that evil moderator quid deleted, or a poor new user was not treated nicely enough.   On your numbers, the reopen review went 3-0 to leave closed.

Comment: @quid If the votes on the (*many*) opinions in this answer mean anything, then likely they target the highlighted boldified opinion "**Do not roll back improvements**". Anything beyond that is a wild guess and should not be used as the basis of any argument. If you want your meta answers to be useful for polling then it is essential to constrain the answer to a *single* opinion. In the past some meta answerers have abused this ambiguity to try to gain support for unpopular opinions. Nowadays we should know better.

Comment: @BillDubuque sure, and I acknowledge this clearly, and most crucially I encouraged Gerry to raise his concern somewhere in a clear way. If he wants to know how much support his view actually has nothing stops him to post an answer arguing for undelete or in the dedicated thread or in a new thread. But most seem to agree it's not a good post. I mean even meta OP said it was in part a "mess."

Comment: @quid It was you - not Gerry - who attempted to make unfounded inferences based on the votes on this post, so it is not Gerry's responsibility to (dis)prove them. Why do you believe that  "*most* seem to agree it's not a good post"? (my emph.)  Did you poll *most* users?

Comment: @BillDubuque well, Gerry brought up scores of comments and other arguably questionable metrics. On the rest show me the users that say it's a good post.  Or go ahead and  argue in favor of the post

Comment: @quid As I mentioned above, I think it is a dupe with nothing novel so it should be deleted. But I think we should be more concerned here with the general principles, hence my remarks. If we have any hope of reaching good compromises on contentious matters then we must strive to assess them as *fairly* as possible.

Comment: @BillDubuque yes. But I don't think anything would have been gained by letting the post run through a couple of more rounds of un-delete. It's clear that opinions are mixed. However, it *seems* to me based on experience that the specific post is rather one where deletion should have the upper hand. IIRC  the last un-delete before this one I decided, I decided for undelete.

Comment: Frankly, you **really** should not edit this post now in this form now after fifty votes were cast. IMO you ought to  leave it to everybody to draw their conclusions. You don't own the interpretation of the votes now either.  Please revert.  I originally intended my first comment to explicitly say that I agree with both points you raised (including the deletion). I now regret that I did not do this. But I won't edit it in.

Comment: Rolled back. I still think only a minority of users misunderstood what I was putting up to vote, but there's a good point to be made against rewriting history.

Comment: @quid, no need to get dramatic here. I did not call you evil, and I didn't make any reference to a "poor new user".

Comment: @GerryMyerson no, but you did try to incite a flag-storm. That's already pretty far out there in what users usually try to do. Worse I cannot  help but feel it was mostly for small reasons, because it was *your* vote that was overturned.

Comment: Re: *Do not roll back improvements.* My experience from the past. Edits which improve wording, MathJax, grammar are usually fairly uncontroversial. If edits add context, it seems to be ok if the context was collected from the OP's comments or from chat. But a few times I have seen users strongly object that the editor is putting words into the asker mouth.

Comment: To include at least one specific example, here is a [link to such discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/conversation/discussion-around-editing-a-question-on-sum-related-to-hn). In that case, the question was later reposted (with added context) by another user.

Comment: A number of times over some years I posted comments in meta to the effect that one should not label a question as "off topic" and "not about mathematics" when the reason for closing is actually lack of "context". This would require software changes, and if the community supported it, it would probably get done. But many people, including some of the moderators, became extremely angry at me for suggesting the idea and said it was irrational and evil. Their behavior was and still remains incomprehensible to me.

Comment: One thing that is clear is that the small group of users who devote a lot of time closing questions were (and probably still are) serving purposes that I am not aware of. And probably a dozen or more have systematically censored discussion of this issue on meta. The forbid everyone to discuss these matters, by closing meta postings on bogus pretexts. I complained to the moderators about this dozens of times over several years without ever once getting any reply. Then I wrote to them to say it appears that the moderators deal only with matters involving a single posting and not with......

Comment: .....persistent patterns of behavior. They never replied to that either. Then I took the matter to the community managers, who never answered. That was probably in 2017. Then I said I was looking into reporting dishonest behavior to an academic department with which a dishonest user was affiliated, since the moderators and community managers were unwilling to reply to my reports to them about it. For that they banned me from posting for one year. This is calculated and persistent dishonesty, and officers of the company have declined to hear about it.

Answer (score 61):

(Posting as an answer, rather than a comment, because I'm curious how many will disagree.)

I think the "little to do with being elementary" dispute strikes at the heart of the underlying issue here.

We expect our questions to be well-formed, clear, and considered. We like them to have a clear, unambiguous answer. We want both the question and the answer to be helpful (and of interest) to future visitors of the site, not just the person who posed the question. We prefer them narrow, in the sense that we can isolate and obliterate one piece of misunderstanding in a compact single answer.

We tend not to like having to intuit (or, as is often the case, outright guess) the genuine source of confusion in the question. We tend not to want to have to explain things that have been explained over and over again, or indeed explain things that the asker already understands but has neglected to mention.

The site's own guidelines reflect this, if you look at the reasons for closing questions.

But, the problem is, this heavily biases against people earlier in their mathematics education. Writing the kinds of questions that we like requires mathematical maturity. It's a skill in itself to be able to reflect and determine what you do and don't understand, let alone pinpoint a specific lack of understanding that's causing you problems. In my experience, mathematics students don't tend to get reliably good at identifying what they don't understand until university (at least). Some students never develop it, and finish their mathematics education under the impression that believing that you understand something in mathematics is a trap for fools, and that there's always some hole in your understanding that someone could point out.

Mathematical maturity is also important for clear communication of mathematics. We ask students for their thoughts on a problem until we're blue in the face, but even if the student has had a myriad of thoughts about a problem, there's no guarantee that they'll be able to communicate even a single one of these thoughts to us. It's even harder when the communication is written, not verbal.

Personally, I honestly believe that a majority of low-level PSQs are written without context, not because of a lack of effort in solving the problem, but simply because the student is incapable of communicating their problem beyond reciting it word for word. When you press these students for more details or thoughts, they may respond with more context, but our own influence in this process should not be ignored; without us asking the right questions, I just don't think they're capable of further mathematical communication.

So, in short, both our personal preferences and the site's guidelines implicitly bias in favour of higher level mathematics, simply because the questions we like require mathematical maturity to formulate.

I'm not necessarily in favour of explicitly changing the guidelines, but I definitely agree that we should be more lenient on beginners.

Comment: *Mathematical* maturity is a very high bar and certainly not *required* to write a reasonable question. It's definitely not required to make sure you aren't making careless mistakes like the ones that were corrected in the referenced post. Frankly, I'm more inclined to believe that it is just plain maturity that is relevant.

Comment: @DerekElkins Well, I'm looking at mathematical maturity as a sliding scale here. A person who can ask a good question may not be "fully" mature yet, if that indeed means something. But, I do think it is a high bar that we implicitly prefer our askers to clear, and I do think it discourages beginners from asking questions. Also, which careless mistakes are you talking about?

Comment: A lot of the observations in this post are correct. However, the current question still seems one where OP just is not really invested in the post. Note: No accept. No reaction at all. And no it is not because OP certainly was discouraged or something. It seems the first close vote and downvote was cast after OP had already left the site (for now). It seems they got what they wanted and left. Maybe to return once the need something next time. That's fine with me to some point.  But I think we should stop to pretend that surely OP tried as best as they could when it just does not seem likely.

Comment: @TheoBendit There was, at the very least, a seeming typo ($y=1/8$ v. $y=\arctan(1/8)$) that was fixed by others, not the OP of the referenced post. Obviously, everyone makes typos, but it is a careless mistake, and a careless but potentially substantive mistake in two lines of text.

Comment: Isn't part of "being lenient with beginners" to assist them by editing to clear up wording and formatting, without violence to the underlying intent?  I've gotten negative feedback for doing so, and it seems that the rollback described in the OP is against this spirit of collaboration.  So I may be projecting, but I found that part of the account disturbing.

Comment: @ quid and Derek Elkins, good points, well taken. This particular example does not demonstrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: Many good points raised here. I want to add the point of view that another major reason for lower level material becoming a target for the janitorial staff is that, at lower level, the chances of a question being an $n$th near duplicate variant increases. I'm not saying that this would necessarily be the most decisive factor, but it definitely plays a role.

Comment: @TheoBendit +1 for the answer, and the final "we should be more lenient on beginners". P.S. I had my share of arguments about that here in meta, which went sour at some point where I dropped off. This is my first comment/post in many months, and likely the last for another long time, so don't expect followups.

Comment: @dxiv I won't expect a follow-up. It's sad that your usage has dropped off. It might be my imagination, but I've been feeling that Meta has (generally) been more welcoming of this view lately.

Comment: Theo, @dxiv. Yes, I think we have more "anti-deletionists" participating in meta discussion now than we had may be a year ago. That is just as well. Making for a more balanced discussion. A remaining problem is that not all of the new entrants have not read the past discussions, and "defenders of the current norms" know (?) better (?) than to rehash past arguments :-) But that will fix itself over time.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You know that I'm not anti-deletionist, right? I've never heard you say anything to the contrary, but I thought I would clear that up, just in case this was your impression. I would more say that deletion is simply not important to me. I participate in it primarily because I know it's important to others. Certainly I can see how anti-deletionists might put their support behind arguments like this, but this argument was not written to oppose deletion. Myself, I'd be happy to help beginners with poor quality questions, and have my answer deleted afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, Theo. Understood. My choice of phrase was not well thougt out. At one point the meta discussion was dominated by C.R.U.D.E. activists to an uncomfortable degree. For us to solve the problems the site is facing, it is necessary that we get more wide spread participation in meta affairs. Otherwise the "policies" won't be palatable to a large enough fraction of users, and hence won't be sustainable. Of course, a wide discussion will increase awareness of differing opinions, which, among reasonable people, will reduce the friction.

Comment: I don't think we are at a point, where sustainable compromises can be discussed, but hopefully, some day... But, yeah, this thread has certainly gotten a different kind of a reception in comparison to the missive @dxiv gave a few months ago.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: This isn't an argument, just a comment. I agree that more participation on meta is needed. I am interested in the idea that the site was dominated by those users. In my mind, a key source of the problem is from when meta was dominated by users who claimed that we can't possible tell which problems are homework and so we should require context, rather than just using our normal sense of which problems are homework. But now, when homework problems are posed with no context, we find that even the lack of context is not a good reason to close homework questions.

Comment: The other issue, in my mind, is that I am not convinced the moderators are willing to enforce guidelines even if they are set by clear consensus on meta. I am not sure how else this site, which is an independent SE community driven by its users, can establish its own policies.  For example, we have not even found a way to address delete/undelete cycles or multiple delete/undelete votes by the same users.

Comment: @CarlMummert You said a lot of things in line with my thinking. I feel that the definition of a PSQ is an imperfect substitute for a homework problem, and we might be better off without such a term. But, what would be ideal? And how to enforce it? Physics has a comprehensive ban on homework, we should (at least) compare notes with them.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I've also no idea why Math SE moderators hasn't yet firmly enforced guidelines, but for the time being it's still okay. I'll note that in the recent SO moderator election many candidates were parading their close+delete statistics as indicative of their commitment to moderator work. The newly elected users said "I've voted 10000+ times to close and 14000+ times to delete for a total of 37000+ votes." and "I have nearly 11k helpful flags (18 decl), 13k close votes and 5k delete votes.".

Comment: Just a note on the "C.R.U.D.E. activists" @JyrkiLahtonen mentioned from years past --- some of us got tired of losing the fight and stopped contributing, as the onslaught of unstopped PSQs and apparent support on Meta for their existence became wearisome.

Comment: @Carl it depends what you mean exactly. I believe that I do try to enforce guidelines. I won't close 200 questions/day though. The main share of the day to day workload must be carried by a distributed effort. The moderators accompany this and make sure that thing move in the right direction. (Maybe that should be discussed elsewhere though.)

Comment: @quid - I do think the moderators enforce the most basic guidelines. I was thinking about the issue of our community developing new ones. Concrete example - I don't think I have ever seen a clear statement from the moderators that, if the community developed a well-supported own policy about repeated close/reopen votes, the moderators would stand behind it and enforce it with warnings and suspensions. Without that kind of support, I don't think the community is likely to really develop such things, or even a framework to develop our own policies beyond the basic ones we inherited from SE.

Comment: Of course, that is just one issue, which may not have much consensus. There are many other issues where the community could in principle develop a framework to make a binding decision about something. I think this can make the site quite frustrating from time to time - there seems to be no system to develop a binding consensus about anything, so users who are not violating the most basic 'rules' have essentially carte blanche to ignore even a strong consensus about more anything that is more subtle.

Comment: @Carl I'd say to some extent this happened. An example would be the contest policy.

Comment: That's true. ...

Answer (score 28):

> **Vote on the question, not the user.**

A good question is a good question, regardless of the user's account age or account status. And a bad question is a bad question, regardless of the user's account age or account status.  If a user has chosen not to familiarize themselves with the site standards, and has gone ahead and posted an off-topic or low-quality question, then so be it. This is independent of question level or the difficulty of the mathematical content.

Polite and kind comments directing them to the relevant site guides are great (and we should be very generous with those, especially for brand new users), but that's orthogonal to the moderation actions involved in downvoting, closing, or deleting.

Comment: Disagree, I am always more generous to new users and their early question, and include both an additive and a multiplicative bias when evaluating how I'll cast my own one vote. A single up vote on a less-than-perfectly formed question will not break the internet, but the tiny thrill a new user might experience from some positive feedback might increase the likelihood of positive future engagements.

Comment: we need more people like @uhoh on the internet...... just clicking a small button wont break the internet, but it could always make someone's day (or ruin if you want to be the spoilsport troll on the net)

Comment: @AdilMohammed there are plenty of people in SE more welcoming than I, but thank you! I suppose though that there are less plenty of people as committed as I to making sure welcoming happens and that unwelcoming things are pointed out and unwelcoming folks are encouraged to be more welcoming.

Answer (score 17):

I have a great deal of sympathy with the general point being made here. I could say a lot - the challenge of maintaining quality whilst genuinely welcoming new contributors to the site is a tough one.

I am not a professional mathematician, but hugely enjoy mathematics - so maybe my approach is idiosyncratic - but I think that in the back of my mind, when I am trying to respond to situations like the one described, I have the question "how can I help the person asking this question to enjoy their mathematics?"

One of the hazards of the site is that some "low quality" questions attract equally low quality answers so fast that there is no time to engage the questioner with how to ask a good question - there is no time to coach good behaviour. It may be that shutting down the possibility of an answer while the quality of the question is addressed could be fine-tuned and protocols around putting on hold could be refined with this in view.

Comment: I agree that what you mention in the final paragraph is a main problem we face. Incidentally, the example given in the question here illustrates it to some extent (the answer is technically sound, but no additional explication or guidance is offered).

Comment: I really like this idea. Is it possible to give some general suggestions as to what fine tunings and protocol refinings might be like?

Answer (score 14):

I feel that the title of this thread is misguided. I see no evidence of this being about the elementary beginner. The asker of your example question has not been seen on the site [since March 30th](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/659057/rayan-saleh). Looks like they got what they wanted. Therefore I suspect (I hope I'm wrong) that:

- You picked the title with the expectation that this way you get more sympathy for your cause (it may or may not have worked).
- Your real goal is to discuss deletion in general as opposed to deletions of questions by elementary beginners, or
- Your goal is to "protect" the answers to such posts from being deleted.

Anyway, let's assume that you truly want to discuss the way we treat newbie beginners, and just happened to pick a bad specific example (IMHO it behooves you to find a better one).

I could actually get behind the idea of using softer gloves with newbies. Theo listed some reasons. They do run contrary to the fundamental goal of the site of being a repository of quality questions and answers, but let's ignore that for a moment for the sake of an argument.

> There are good reasons for handling a post by a beginner differently, but **I will not extend the same liberties to answerers of low-quality questions.**

I could agree not to delete a post by a newbie, if:

- the first person wanting to answer the question engages with the asker, tries to elicit an explanation for the missing context, points the newbie to the resources and so on, and
- any person wanting to answer the questions spends at least 15 minutes *searching the site* for (near) duplicates. If they find one, then they must A) post a link to the potential dupe target, B) refrain from answering, but C) are more than welcome to post their answer to the original if they think that is prudent.

Many users do the first bullet, but they are IMNSHO too eager to post any answer.

The thinking here is that the same people who think the new question is worth answering are the people who should do these rounds of checks. In particular if the would-be-answerer is a trusted user, they should take the role of a mentor-on-duty as opposed to rush to answer.

For the record:

- I practice what I preach. I am getting better with Approach0 as well as the on-site search engine, but I spend a signficant fraction of my time on main searching. I have also referred hundreds of new users to [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). If all the upvoters to Jack's rant (including himself) would do the same, the problem might be solved. Unless you, my reader, take part in that effort, you have little right to complain about the current state of affairs. The gall... (shakes head).
- The founder of SE, in [a blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/) suggested that in his opinion a newbie programmer should spend 98% of their time on StackOverflow searching. We may not have yet covered math as comprehensively as they have covered programming, but we are competitive. We should put a lot more effort educating newbies about the available search engines. True, google doesn't grok TeX, and neither does that newbie, so let's be reasonable. More reason to insist that the answerers do their part searching.

Comment: The [In search of a question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question) chatroom may be relevant.

Comment: I repeat: In the case of a low quality question the answerers are also in the focus of my "janitorial" work. If the site were smaller, we could more easily do more to help new users get up to speed. As [Shog9 points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/5001846) this does not scale well for a large site. It is up to the interested answerer to take the role of a mentor. Don't get me wrong, many of them do! It is those users that regularly show up answering LQ question but don't give the noob help in asking that I want to reach. I'm sure we can talk it over.

Comment: Why do you believe "this does not scale well"?

Comment: @BillDubuque The number of people referring newbies to "How to ask a good question" and other similar guides seems to be almost a constant, but the number of newbies is increasing. The ratio is becoming worse. Shog9 at least thinks this is inevitable, when the site keeps growing. I didn't want to believe that, but it seems to be happening.

Comment: If all the people upvoting Jack's posts would guide as many newbies as I do, the problem might be solved. But, I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @BillDubuque see the last paragraph of  Mark Bennet's answer. This is closely linked to the high turn-over.

Comment: Just want to point out that OP did return to the site yesterday.

Answer (score 12):

By popular demand, yet another answer.

The subject has various aspects. Let me start with:

### The specific post.

The question mentioned in this meta post falls into a category that some consider as not appropriate for the site (including me). It is very common that such questions get closed and deleted. Of course, others disagree with doing this, and the subject of deletions and closures of such posts was discussed to great length at various times. Indeed, only recently at the initiative of OP: [What are the merits, if there is any, of deleting (correctly) answered questions in the main site of MSE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29972/what-are-the-merits-if-there-is-any-of-deleting-correctly-answered-questions) and I had provided an answer there.

There does not seem to be anything particular about the post. Thus, focused on this one post, there is no case for creating an entire meta thread to draw attention to it, doing so is frowned upon by some. If anything, a request to undelete it, could have been posted in the dedicated thread.

### Why did I re-delete it right away?

When a post is in a un-delete cycle (the post had been deleted twice and undeleted twice when I acted) it is common practice that a moderator, or moderators collectively, decide the fate of the question.

The reason I acted rather quickly is that due to the high visibility that was just given via the meta post, based on earlier experience, it was a given that un-delete and open-close conflict would rather escalate. Letting play out such conflicts does not lead anywhere. Moreover, as I remarked earlier in a comment, to focus the attention of numerous users via meta on some particular post that until then had low visibility, is not at all ideal and can lead to problems especially when the post-owners are not involved in the meta. The idea that 'the community' would have reached a consensus on this post strikes me as wishful thinking.

Thus, I am firmly convinced that it was the right course of action to prevent drive-by actions of various forms on this one particular post.

An alternative action to achieve this would have been to lock the post (undeleted). Retrospectively, this might have prevented some problems, but as I said, I decided to put the post back into the state where it was prior to the meta post. Moreover, as said, I am also personally of the opinion that such posts should be deleted. While the decision was taken by me alone, I did right away put the other moderators into the loop, saying that if there is considerable disagreement with the post being deleted, then it could be undone.  Until now, I still do not see much disagreement against the post being deleted (maybe against how and why it was deleted, but that's a separate concern).

### Comment on the timeline

While the meta OP does a reasonably good job at explaining the situation,  I think some clarifications about the timeline might be helpful, especially as not everybody can know this and most cannot know it all at least no easily (yes, partly me fault, see above).

The question was asked on March 29th, in the early evening (all times in UTC, that is "SE time"), was answered near instantly and a first, incomplete, edit happened.

The question was then closed slightly more than a day later (very early on March 31st).

Then a bit more than two days later early afternoon of April 2nd a motion to delete the post started (common practice), via vote and post in CRUDE.

*Right after that*, likely as a reaction to it but maybe independently, the question was edited for a second time and a competing motion to reopen the post was set in place.

Thus the actual course of events is somewhat different from the impression OP tries to convey (even though what they wrote is not literally false).

### Summary on the post

On its own merits, there is no reason to try to preserved that post. It is routine and very localized, and was presented in a sloppy way. In my opinion, it should not have been answered. As said, the merits of deleting such post got discussed recently  [What are the merits, if there is any, of deleting (correctly) answered questions in the main site of MSE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29972/what-are-the-merits-if-there-is-any-of-deleting-correctly-answered-questions) and I had provided an answer there (to the same OP).

### What about "elementary beginners"?

The simplest answer is to say it does not matter we judge the posts on their merits, a point advocated in other answers. Those that follow this meta know that I am personally in itself not hostile to this approach, and I though this also came through in comments I had left here.

However, those that follow this meta know too that this is not at all in line with historical practice and any number of earlier discussions, and most crucially it is not at all in line with the thrust of this meta post, which specifically focuses on being "more generous to elementary beginners" doubling down and stressing that I did not get it because it was about "beginners" and not elementary questions, about "**human beings**". So, there I followed there line of reasoning, rather than to simply dismiss the idea with "we don't care, lets only talk about the post."

I will freely admit that I was quite annoyed, actually still am, though I should have handled it better,  when this then was completely turned around and I was accused of having promoted the idea that the deletion of the post is only because of the main OP not being responsive. This is not my position.

What I do think is that  **if** somebody considers to make accommodations based on the (presumed) personal context of the poster, which is what that entire thread is about,  **then** they should take the full picture into account. Merely that the account is new and the question is simple does not strike me as sufficient to envision any sort of exceptions, not only but also as it's trivial to get a new account. So, one can always be "new." (I do not want to imply this was the case here.)

### What about being "more generous"?

The initial reaction to the question was generous. It was answered near instantly and even improved, only slightly but still. Then later it was reviewed in view of its suitability to contribute to the pool of knowledge that we try to create and was found lacking. Thus it was put on hold and then scheduled for deletion.

One could say, first, we helped the individual, then once this was done, we switched the focus to the interests of the site. That actually seems like a reasonable compromise between different visions of the site.

The casual and new users often don't mind all that much what happens to their posts down the road. Flags by new users demanding why no answers is forthcoming already are not rare, flags asking about disappearing posts happen sometimes but really it doesn't seem to be of much concern, at least as long as new questions can be asked.

Those that mostly complain are those that answer a lot. Now, that's also understandable, and we can discuss how to balance things out, but that's a separate concern.

Comment: Why did you delete it? I know you left a comment, but this doesn't allow anyone to undelete it. Moderator deletion should be reversible, but it isn't.

Comment: @MattSamuel how do you propose we resolve a situation were 3 users keep voting to undelete while 3 users keep voting to delete? // On why I deleted, could you please point out specifically what point is open after having read this post and the linked thread?

Comment: Given the lack of reply, I take it @MattSamuel you have no proposal and everything is clear now.

Comment: No, just busy day. You could've locked it instead.

Comment: Did you read the post at all before commenting here? 'An alternative action to achieve this would have been to lock the post (undeleted). Retrospectively, this might have prevented some problems, but [...] '

Comment: "a situation were 3 users keep voting to undelete while 3 users keep voting to delete" The question was deleted (by vote) twice, and not by the same three users, and undeleted twice, and not by the same three users. Only one user voted to delete twice, and only one user voted to undelete twice.

Comment: @GerryMyerson my question was in reply to the assertion that mod-del should be reversible. It is not, by design, in order to be able to more easily resolved situations like the one I described. It is correct that the current situation does not match exactly the one I described. Yet in essence it is the same. It is arguably even worse that already more users are involved on both sides. // I hope that all those that say 'lock' do realize that this would then deprive users to vote to redelete, so that if 'the community should be able to vote' is the argument there is no difference.

Comment: I am quite new to this site, and new to maths, the problem i see with deleting such posts, is that users like me then have to ask those elementary questions over and over again. It’s not easy to understand some of the posts even if they cover the topic i am currently studying, bc of the more formal mathematical way they are written in. I am getting more and more used to a mathematical line of thought, and how to express myself, such posts (and eventually how they are asked) could be to the advantage of other learners

Comment: @Ang Search the site. And then search some more. If your question is elementary, the answer already is there with a high probability.

Answer (score 7):

**Regardless of the fate of this question, the attention span of the asker should never be used as a criterion for casting delete votes.**

I have observed a moderator(!) suggest, in multiple comments on this meta question and its answers, that the OP's lack of involvement with the site is in some way relevant to the fact that their question got deleted. I encouraged that moderator to post an answer explaining that relevance in more detail, but the moderator refused to do so. This is unfortunate, because it forces me to guess what that moderator actually meant by those comments.

Charitably, this was a bad question, and probably deserved to be deleted. But that's beside the point. We should never judge the value of a question by the behavior of the asker. A question's value to readers is substantially more important than its value to the single person who happened to post it.

I don't know if that is what the moderator intended by these comments. I hope it isn't. But I wanted to state, clearly and on the record, that the inattention of the questioner is not a valid basis for deleting questions.

(Obviously, if a question is *already* eligible for deletion, then the asker's inattention may result in it actually being deleted, or remaining deleted, and in some cases this may happen faster than if the asker was attentive and unsuccessfully tried to salvage their question. But that's a separate issue.)

Comment: I assume  this goes both ways. If so, please, make it explicit. If not please explain why. In particular, you ought to be in strong disagreement with the question.

Comment: @quid: Your ongoing reticence to write an answer, despite clearly holding strong opinions that no other answer expresses, continues to baffle me.

Comment: Maybe address the point I raised rather then speculating around. Again, if we agree to  judge the question on its merits only the entire thread is pointless. (Which indeed it is, if you ask me, mostly since it's a duplicate.)

Comment: @quid: I have mixed feelings about this whole thread. I think it is important that we recognize the privileges we enjoy as people versed in mathematics, which may well justify the asymmetry which you are objecting to. At the same time, I think this discussion is a poor example of the problem. Regardless, I decline to convert my answer, which is specific to a single issue, into a broad statement of opinion which would detract from my point. If you disagree with me, please write your own answer.

Comment: I think your answer in this form is borderline dishonest, especially since your intent is to create vote-turn out, since it is phrased in a way as to appeal to the anti-delete fraction, while when the principle would be thought to its end it would have the exact opposite effect.

Comment: @quid: There are no sides. This is about what's best for the site.

Comment: Is your position that questions should be judge on the merits of the post only: yes or no?

Comment: @quid: I believe that is a false dichotomy, so neither.

Comment: How is it a false dichotomy?

Comment: Also to recall (added emphasis) "The **post** was very sloppily written." was the first thing I said.

Comment: @quid: This discussion is not related to improving my meta answer, so I will now disengage.

Comment: I raised a specific point, by pointing out that it seems that your answer is not thought through or willfully manipulative. It is very hard to understand how you in good faith can attack me for taking the OP's action into account, and say nothing regarding this to OP of the meta question.

Comment: @quid: I am not attacking you. I deliberately avoided assigning any motives to you, and even said that it was a bad question. Clearly, there is nothing more that I can do to change your opinion of me and my answer, but I have done everything in my power to be respectful and evenhanded here.

Comment: Obviously your are attacking me. See first comment in this thread, for instance. Anyway, so I surmise that you agree the question can be deleted without issue, you only object to me  discussing the idea with meta OP if and how the status  and the actions of main OP should be factored in.

Comment: @quid: I said exactly what I meant to say in my answer. I *deliberately did not* say anything else, because I feel conflicted about the other aspects of this meta, and also because I do not feel that this meta is the proper vehicle for discussing those aspects. I find your continued hostility very uncomfortable, and I do not wish to discuss this matter with you any further. If this is an "attack," then I apologize for offending you. Regardless, I will not respond again.

Comment: You either completely misunderstand the entire situation or willfully distort it. My position  is: the question should be deleted on its merits, and no we should not make an exception based on the status of main OP contrary to what is suggested by meta OP.

Comment: @quid Just out of curiosity, do you *expect* to have a productive conversation starting from "you either completely misunderstand […] or willfully distort"? Moderators ought to be setting a higher example.

Comment: @T.Bongers do you think your comment is constructive?

Comment: @quid I'd like to think it's a reminder that there's a person at the other end of the ethernet cables. Whether you find it constructive or not is up to you.

Comment: @T.Bongers it's certainly true that I could, and likely should have, reacted more diplomatically. That said, the point Kevin tries to make is still very weird to me. They seem to jump on a detail without taking the context into account. Again, the entire thread is about taking the postER into account.

Comment: @Kevin I don't agree with the main point of your post. If an asker is unresponsive to requests to edit their question and improve it, then I'm happy deleting the post more quickly - if the asker won't bother editing their question to bring it up to snuff, it's not the community's job to. On the other hand, a responsive asker who's trying to actively improve their question is a completely different case.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I wasn't really focused on the "more quickly" angle so much as the basic "does it get deleted at all?" question.

Comment: 'I wasn't really focused on the "more quickly" angle' features prominently in OP though 'and then immediately voted to delete the post again while it is "on-hold".'

Comment: Not sure what the rest of these comments are about, but I wanted to point out that not every asker necessarily has hours of available internet time to respond within a couple hours to edits or suggestions or even answers.

Comment: @kcrisman and if they find a question has been closed or deleted in that time, they as the op still have the ability to see what the discussion and reasons for doing so were and can then improve the existing version and request reopening or ask again with improvements, so I think that is a moot point.

Comment: Well, it probably depends - presumably the sort of asker asking this sort of question may not be able to/be willing to/be interested in taking the time to figure out how all that works.  "Your question was deleted" sounds pretty bad to a first-timer who isn't familiar with the culture of these Q&A sites, or so I would presume.  But point taken.

Comment: @quid: Please do not ping my inbox again. I consider the discussion closed and will not respond.

Comment: It seems to me that the actions of the asker are *key* to evaluating a question.  In this case the OP ignored the advice they received when they posted the question, and then didn't edit the question for two days after it was closed.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer the question, but I'd like to comment on Theo Bendit's comment:

> We tend not to like having to intuit (or, as is often the case,
>   outright guess) the genuine source of confusion in the question. We
>   tend not to want to have to explain things that have been explained
>   over and over again, or indeed explain things that the asker already
>   understands but has neglected to mention.

As a purely descriptive comment, this is basically correct: most people here don't like having to puzzle out what's really being asked, they'd rather read unambiguous mathematical questions, especially when those questions are perceived as elementary.

**However** one of the things that makes a great teacher is the ability to puzzle out what's being asked in contexts where the student lacks the vocabulary or linguistic devices to directly ask their question. I think the answer-writers on this website should use such questions as opportunities to build this very important muscle, rather than blaming students for not having skills that realistically, someone at their level is likely not to have. Curiosity should be rewarded, not punished. I also disagree with the use of the word "confusion" here. Not having the language to ask the question you're trying to ask is different to being "confused", and I've always found teachers who ask things "what are you confused about?" pretty obnoxious, and usually a lot more ignorant than they realize.

Also, being a good teacher inevitably involves explaining things that have been explained over and over again, or else creating something to do this task for you (like a blog post, or a text snippet that can be copied-and-pasted where needed). That's just part of being a teacher. If you can't be bothered to do this, fine, but please don't harass the OP over this. Just be silent and look for questions elsewhere. Perhaps someone else will come along with the energy to help; why should they be blocked by an [On Hold] tag when they're willing to help? The purpose of these tags should be to stop questions that display no interest in the subject matter, not to block questions that display "too much" interest in the subject matter.

Comment: For this to work everybody would have to show some discipline though. What often happens in practice is that users over-eager to "help" answer based on their reading of the question, worse not even making explicit that their answer is based on some assumption.  Then we get competing interpretations etc. If you want to help an asker to clarify their question, by all means do so.

Comment: SE even built a feature for that: comments. They still work once the question is on hold/closed. Unclear question -> on hold -> exchange with OP to clarify -> edit -> reopen, is the way to go. *Not* everybody answers whatever they think might be intended. That's precisely why we put questions on hold. Of course that's arguably a cumbersome process, but let's not forget that we are talking about dedicated teachers here to help, not folks  that quickly want to cash in some points for an answer launched in a fire-and-forget mindset.

Comment: @quid, is that really a problem though? A good answer to such questions is often of the form: "I think you're asking A. If so, the answer is A'. However, you might also be asking B. If so, the answer is B'. In order to ask clearer questions in future, be mindful of the distinction between X and X'. The difference is Y."

Comment: @quid, continuing... If someone posts the answer "I think you're asking asking A. If so, the answer is A'." and someone else posts the answer "However, you might also be asking B. If so, the answer is B'. In order to ask clearer questions in future, be mindful of the distinction between X and X'. The difference is Y." I consider that the question is fully answered at this point.

Comment: @quid, this happened [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3175604/42339) for example.

Comment: Yes, it is a real problem, not last because often the answers are not of the form you describe. The example you give is a bit peculiar in that it's not a particularly unclear question in my opinion (it's not a great question for other reasons and I had almost closed it back then, but that's orthogonal). I do not really consider your answer as appropriate, at least not as an answer. Further,  the entire idea of the platform is conceived around answering to the point and reasonably scoped questions, not conversational interactions prompted by some question-like text snippet.

Comment: @quid, can you elaborate a bit on what (in your opinion) the problem is with the linked question and/or my answer? It seems to me that everything is well and dandy therein, except that I probably should have emphasized that the ambiguity is coming from the word "space"...

Comment: One problem is that apparently it is not clear enough. Another is what is "simple" supposed to mean? Why is OP asking this? Etc. In brief it lacks context. That said, as sometimes comes up, giving context for somewhat natural (counter) examples one seeks is not always easy and not always crucial. It's not that bad. That is why I did not close it.

Comment: I don't really grasp your animus against the word "confusion". I've only ever heard it used when a student is trying to digest concepts that have previously been taught. The information on the concept has previously been conveyed, and the student is trying to translate this into understanding. Surely "confusion", in the sense of [uncertainty about what is intended](https://www.google.com/search?q=confusion), is appropriate, even if it comes from a misunderstanding of the language involved?

Comment: @TheoBendit, different people interpret words differently, but for me, confusion is an emotional state. "I'm feeling confused..." Usually, when someone doesn't know how to ask the questions they want to ask, it's not an emotional state they're in, it's just that they don't know how to ask their question. Indeed, oftentimes, they're thinking much more clearly than their colleagues and are. They're probably the only student who is not confused about the relevant issues. Calling them "confused" imo punishes them for being a better student than other students.

Comment: Hmm, I'll keep that in mind in future.