# Under what criteria should we remove questions from the HNQ list?

Tags: discussion, moderators, hot-questions-list

Since the Hot Network Questions list was [revamped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt) 6 months ago, moderators have had the power to remove questions from the list. As [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija), the community manager for the SE network says,

> I recommend each site have a meta discussion with guidance for moderators about when - if ever - a question should be removed.

I have noticed our moderation team have been exercising this power (specifically, it always seems to be [Asaf Karagila](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila)). Most of the choices I agree with, but some I find questionable. So, I think we should outline some guidelines for a question to be removed from the HNQ list.

Specifically, I would like to discuss the following points:

1. Should an HNQ be removed if the question is not interesting, but it has lead to interesting answers?
2. Should an HNQ be removed if it is an interesting question, but has not generated interesting answers?
3. Is a lack of context grounds for removing otherwise interesting questions/answers from the HNQ?
4. Should we adopt a policy of removing all homework questions from the HNQ?
5. Given that controversy (which was the cause for the HNQ revamp) is an extremely rare issue for mathematics questions, should we be removing questions from the HNQ at all?
6. (Added, from discussion below my answer) Should there be any guidelines at all for removing questions from the HNQ?
7. (Another added question, after discussing with quid) Should we, as a community, care about HNQs at all?

Comment: I'd love to write something, but I am hosting a workshop that starts this week, so I will only join in by the end of the week, or even after the weekend.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, what terrible timing. :-)

Comment: Let me just add a quick thing. When this feature was into the site, there was some discussion amongst the moderators. We had some agreement that it is better to err on the side of removal, since the natural state of a question is not on HNQ anyway. And in general HNQ questions should be good representation of content we want to encourage. So context, presentation, etc. I personally also remove lazy titles as well, since they should be improved and almost always include $\rm\LaTeX$ that would disqualify them anyway.

Comment: In favour of 4. on condition of lack of sufficient context (relates to 3.) Removing all HW questions may be too extreme as quite a few of them are well-written with attempts by asker etc. And maybe 4. should be generalised to include contest problems.

Comment: In favour of 3. In a way, lack of context are grounds as a question is knocked off the HNQ once closed (presumably off-topic in this case). "Interesting" is another matter, and has caused considerable controversy ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3313022/timeline)). IMO interesting LQ HW/contest problems should be removed; the asker doesn't deserve the upvotes/attention their post gets for poorly asking something not of their own creation (relates to 4.) The controversy lies in interesting apparently self-motivated questions without evidence of actual motivation from the asker.

Comment: I am not sure whether the claim that "controversy is an extremely rare issue" for questions on this site. There was definitely a fair share of close/reopen, detele/undelete wars, including some questions that were in the HNQ list. (It all probably depends on what *kind* of controversy you have in mind.)

Comment: I suppose that for the purposes of this discussion it might be useful to check which questions have been removed from the HNQ. Here is a [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) query which lists such removals: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1013246/questions-removed-from-hnq-by-mods?num=500

Comment: @MartinSleziak Just to (hopefully) clarify: due to the fact that Theo mentions that "controversy (...) was the cause for the HNQ revamp", I think he doesn't mean controversy in a broad sense of the word, but controversial posts in the sense of  involving a political/psychological/social disrespectful/improper/sensitive aspect. This is indeed rare in MathSE. (Although it has happened before.)

Comment: Theo, just to point out, I did find the time today...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I was sleeping! I have replied in the form of an answer.

Comment: To confirm, I am indeed talking about the kind of controversy that Aloizio Macedo mentions. More broadly, I'm talking about controversy that affects people outside this community; things that would draw members of the general public to click on a question more out of outrage (or the expectation thereof) than interest in the mathematical content.

Comment: I have posted one SEDE query related to HNQs in the above comment. You can find a few more queries related to this topic [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/98467/2019/9/10). Feel free to use the room also for any related discussion which seems more suitable for chat than for comments.

Comment: A dual question: [What are the criteria for questions to be selected for Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/172557)

Comment: According to the query in @Martin 's prior comment, about 97.4% of the 500 questions removed by mods in the last 5 months were executed by Asaf. I don't think it is good that a single user execises so much control over what posts we expose to the global SE community. Many posts that would do a good job of educating global readers are wrongly being blocked

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35045

Answer (score 13):

Thank you for replying Asaf. This is my response to your post. There's plenty of stuff here that I agree with to some extent. I do have some concerns though.

Firstly, I would have liked it if the community was privy to the discussion between the moderators about when to remove questions from the HNQ. This could easily have been a meta post a long time ago. We are discussing it now, but I get the impression that we are discussing a policy decision that was made in the past, rather than being a part of formulating policy.

Secondly, I'm broadly worried that we are being too prescriptive in determining what's "hot" and what isn't. I see the HNQ as a way of sowing greater interest in mathematics amongst the SE network, and various members of the wider public. What our more learned members might see as an utterly mundane "low-interest" question, might be still of interest to people for whom the subject never quite clicked ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347226/are-a-b-c-d-e-and-a-b-c-d-e-the-same-set)). For that reason, I can't commit to this idea that we should be constantly fighting the algorithm, which I do think is largely competent at sniffing out general appeal.

I'm almost always in favour of mathematical outreach (though my introverted self finds it personally difficult). Mathematical anxiety and mental blocks are, in my opinion, one of the most serious issues facing our discipline today. The HNQ is a good way of showing people, who don't consider themselves interested in maths, tidbits of maths that they are more likely to find interesting. It's an ongoing debate against all of the common negative perceptions of mathematics (e.g. it's irrelevant, boring, just algorithms, too hard for most people to get, etc).

Basically, I think I would prefer (though this is not a firm opinion yet) for there to be less interference in the HNQ. If a title is bad, for whatever reason, then edit it, and see if the question stays in the HNQ. If that means adding in Latex, then so be it; make sure the question fits into MSE first, and let the HNQ algorithm do its thing.

Primarily, I want to encourage clear questions with well-written answers, and leave questions of interest up to the algorithm. If a question lacks context, then close it for that reason, but I don't think it's necessary to hold HNQs to a higher standard, in the hope that all the context will absorb in the minds of people asking questions to get help with their homework. If for no other reason, I think it'd simply be ineffective. As an example, [the question that prompted me to launch this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348530/proving-this-non-empty-set-and-binary-operation-is-a-group). It provides adequate (but not exemplary) context, in my opinion.

I also don't generally feel comfortable with reasoning based on perceptions about the asker. This includes your disgust at people who title their questions to be clickbait, as well as SimpliFire's comments about people "deserving" of HNQ status. (Maths people being judgemental is another negative perception of mathematics that I prefer to combat, even if there is a grain of truth in it.) Again, I think, edit the title. If they start an edit war, then remove them from the HNQ and maybe talk to them about SE etiquette.

As I said, it's not really a firm opinion yet, but my impression of the policy used so far is that it's too prescriptive and smacks of judgement. I don't really see people "working for the HNQ" as a really big problem, and while context-free questions are a problem, if we keep our usual regimen of closing them (and writing more informative titles), the HNQ should contribute to this problem very little.

Comment: Well, first it seems it was not a big deal for half a year. Now, of course  if one wants to make a big deal of it, it becomes a big deal. Since some on this site have the tendency to make a big deal of about everything, we specifically decided to go ahead and see how it works out. For half a year for all I know no one complained.

Comment: @quid Are you talking about my "Firstly..." paragraph? I don't think it was a big deal, but I do think a discussion with the community would have been the better move. Put another way, for however long the HNQ list was implemented before 6 months ago, having no ability to remove HNQs wasn't a big deal for MSE, so we could have not removed questions until the community reached a decision. I don't have major complaints about the questions removed, and if the policy continues as is, I wouldn't have major objections, but I do think the community should have been part of the discussion.

Comment: As a matter of fact plenty of math questions were removed from the network HNQ before that implementation of the feature, via adding MathJax to the title, either organically, or specifically or something in between. This was somewhat of a gray area but it happened often enough. .

Comment: And sorry but this  it was not a big deal is just false. At numerous occasions some users  vented that this HNQ is an anti feature, completely biases the little value score might have, creates noise on some threads, etc. At least several, not to say plenty, users hate(d) the feature, and many more found it something between silly and irrelevant.

Comment: @quid Point taken. On the topic of your point, do you recall the outrage over the autocratic decision-making made by SE staff on the topic of HNQs? It probably would have helped if the staff had consulted the community before implementing changes...

Comment: Explain why this Q you answered deserves more than five hours in the limelight? Maybe also consider that removing items makes places for new items, I mean it's never the case that the HNQ sidebar is empty! Alright maybe we create an under representation of math, honestly I am not sure that even happens, but would have to check the details. Yet, even if so, maybe other sites might be more in need of publicity then one of the largest sites.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you refer to. Maybe that  at some point some sites were globally taken of the HNQ without much discussion. I really don't think that this is quite comparable on various levels. Further realistically the entire thing is moot. Moderators and only moderators can remove it, as long as the critera leave some reasonable room of interpretation, and I don't see how it could be otherwise, we are simply back to what we have namely that mods remove at their discretion.

Comment: Why should I have to justify that? Are we thinking of implementing a five hour time limit for all maths questions in the HNQ? If not, then this line of inquiry seems disingenuous. I thought the HNQ algorithm would replace it once another question become more "hot". Since specific action was taken with this question by the mods, to remove it before another question supplanted it, I don't think it's unfair to want to talk about their reasons for doing so. And while guidelines will always have room for interpretation, that doesn't mean people in power get to make all decisions for themselves.

Comment: Now, one could argue that the community should be asked for each Q, but that's not feasible as it's time critical. If we discuss two days if we remove or not it's moot. This was actually considered in the internal discussion.

Comment: @quid Right, but that's **not** what I'm arguing. I've never expressed opposition to a blanket policy, one that mods are free to interpret as they see fit in a case-by-case basis. I just wanted the community to help shape this policy, not just for the mods to decide for themselves. If the community gets literally no say in this, then why even have a discussion in the first place? Why not every mod for themselves? We're a community, and your reluctance to even acknowledge the value of discussion with the community frankly baffles me.

Comment: It basically is every mod for themselves. Every mod that does not think a question there is good publicity for the site removes it and that's that.

Comment: "Not good publicity" is maybe not strictly all there is to it, there is no point in having things voted out of proportion, which means exposure should not be too long. Further for some questions the exposure creates (or is suceptible to create) too many answers, too many comments. Etc.

Comment: @quid So, I have, in the past, encountered a mathematician who doesn't like latin squares, and calls it "toy mathematics". Hypothetically, if a fellow mod decided to start removing good, interesting, well-written questions about latin squares simply because they didn't believe anyone should find such things interesting, would you stand by their practices?

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't think it is worth anyones while to entertain this subject in depth. I don't think it is of relevance to have Latin squares Q in the HNQ, I also don't think it is of any relevance to make specifically a point of not having Latin squares in the HNQ. I don't see a reason to discriminate Latin square Q in this why, but if now somebody would do so, I am not sure I would care all that much. It's mostly irrelevant. Why do you care so much some Q is in the HNQ? Mostly users seem to be interested for bad reasons, like greed and vanity. Maybe there are others. Which?

Comment: @quid Right, good to know. I already explained my interest in the HNQ in my answer above. I don't care much at all about any individual questions in the HNQ; I used the question I answered as an example, but I'm fine with it being off the HNQ. The fact is, I have seen a handful of similar examples that I don't agree with (none that I have such a convenient link to share), and I wanted to discuss **policy**, not the specific implementation. I really don't appreciate you trying to shoehorn an ad hominem in here. I have *plenty* of reputation, and I will delete my answer on request.

Comment: @quid I have never made an attack on your character, and I would appreciate if you, a moderator no less, would extend me the same courtesy when engaging in discussion.

Comment: "a good way of showing people, who don't consider themselves interested in maths, tidbits of maths that they are more likely to find interesting" like sets equipped with binary operations that should be shown to be groups?

Comment: @quid Sure, why not? Plenty of people who peel away from mathematics learn about groups, and struggle with proving them. It was a fun little exercise, and I think worthy of interested people seeing and trying for themselves. But again, I feel like you are trying to get me to justify one small example, which is not (and never has been) the point.

Comment: @quid Since you seem to be ascribing ulterior motives to my arguments, I would like to bring your attention to [this now deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180447/is-a-vector-space-a-subspace-of-itself), which I answered and subsequently flagged to have **removed** from the HNQ list once I saw my answer being up-voted too many times.

Comment: Mostly it's not the ulterior motives that annoy me. It's first that I think it is a waste of time. And, second it is a sense of entitlement running through the entire thread. So if you flag it it's apparently fine that a mod reacts to it? What actually should we have done with your flag except deciding something in some way?

Comment: @quid Let me refer you back to [my previous comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list/30673?noredirect=1#comment132988_30673). The flag was to bring to the mods' attention, for them to act as they see fit. Up until then, I had not noticed a question removed from the HNQ; I wasn't even sure if that was something we were doing. There's nothing wrong with mods acting at their discretion (obviously, this needs to happen a lot), but formulating guiding policy with the community is almost always a positive thing.

Comment: The meta Q here already put a spin on the subject. You did not start a debate to have a debate. You started a thread to make your point of view clear. That's arguably still fine, but it's not the same.

Comment: No @quid, that's not why I started the debate. I deliberately did not share my opinions initially, to encourage other viewpoints to surface first. I replied after [Asaf's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list/30673?noredirect=1#comment132969_30671), which I did so as not to be ungrateful for his time (which is in short supply at the moment). I tried not to be leading on any of my questions, except 5, and only because I think most people would answer yes without thinking about the wider context.

Comment: Even I would answer "yes" to the 5th question, despite it being leading towards "no"!

Comment: Of course the five sub-questions put a spin on it. The first two mention answers or the absences thereof. Which directs the attention to answers. Of course somebody could say in reply "We  should not care about answers at all instead we should focus on typesetting and aspects of presentation in the question". But those questions are likely to set of a different debate then if you had asked something that put an aspect of the Q in the center.

Comment: @quid This is a Q&A site. It has *always* been my impression that we are showcasing the As as much as the Qs. Whenever I have read an HNQ from another site, I never stop at just reading the question; I also read the answers, or the first few at least (puzzling being the notable exception). Note that two of the five questions mention answers *and* questions, while the another two mention only questions. I *strenuously* disagree that I have put any undue weight on the answers aspect.

Comment: @quid If you can better formulate this discussion, then I encourage you to do so. I would be happy to accept this question be merged with one you've written on the same topic. This is a discussion I would like to have, but I'm really not married to the wording of the meta post in any shape or form.

Comment: It's trivial. Copy the remark of Catija as you did and add. It seems to me we did not yet have such a debate. And then maybe ask for opinions. Or maybe you could have started by  asking the moderators what their current approach is? Instead **you** decide to start a process with the goal of imposing guidelines for the moderators actions along some lines you laid out.

Comment: @quid So, my bias is that I wanted to participate in the moderation of this community? [At Stack Exchange, we believe moderation starts with the community itself.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) The point of electing people to positions of power is not so that they can then ignore everyone and just do whatever they want!

Comment: The 5 questions are there to kick-start discussion. I could have put Catija's quote, but that seems like a lazy question to me. "Hey, this person recommended we talk about something. So, um, just talk I guess". I wouldn't bother answering a question like that; the asker just seems disinterested in topic.

Comment: Let me put it this way  you go directly from  "some [choices] I find questionable. So, I think we should outline some guidelines for a question to be removed from the HNQ list" to 'Lets start to discuss the guidelines.' The missing step there is to check if there is a shared sentiment that there is a need for guidelines. Plus, any interest in understanding what is specifically done right now.

Comment: @quid Yes, actually, I concede that this would have been a good opening question. I actually thought that there weren't guidelines, and I was reasonably OK with how the HNQ was treated before. It was only when Asaf mentioned that there was a discussion amongst mods about when to use this power that I became a little disappointed. I couldn't see why such discussions couldn't have happened on meta instead, and I still don't. If the mods just acted of their own accord, independently, I would still want to discuss this, but I wouldn't have felt disappointed.

Comment: In a way I do understand that. I would say the discussion was more a brief exchange that everyone is more or less on the same page. My skepticism is mostly based in conviction that there is not all that much to discuss usefully. But, looking back at the exchange above, I  have to apologize for being uncharitable and impatient.

Comment: Thank you @quid, I appreciate that. I really sympathise with that conviction. You have to remember that the maths HNQs are not really for us! They are for other people, outside the community, and for the site traffic itself. I guess it's an uphill battle to convince people here that they're worth thinking about at all.

Comment: Theo, really, your example is "Discrete Math easy question"? That title **sucks**. That title tells you almost nothing about what's going on with the question. And lo and behold, the question was given a proper title which would have excluded it from the HNQ list anyway. As I said, sometimes I don't have the time to edit, and my reasoning for removing something from the HNQ list is due to the fact that a proper title would do that anyway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh the title is atrocious! There's plenty of other things wrong with it (I'm absolutely fine with its fate). But, it's the kind of elementary question that I worry we might remove even if it were posed better, simply because it's not interesting or novel enough. I picked it off the removed HNQ questions because it has been on the list previously, meaning the algorithm determined that a bunch of people were interested in the question, despite how elementary it is.

Comment: @Theo: But the smashing odds is that an elementary question like this will have math in its title. If it doesn't, then it's really because of a "lazy title" symptom. You want people to see good math? Me too. I what them to see a well formulated and well posed question. Not something to reinforce the idea that this is a homework mill.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've [spoken previously](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30038/can-we-please-be-more-generous-to-elementary-beginners/30043#30043) about how our standards for questions bias away from elementary questions. If we try to limit HNQs to exemplify these standards, then we will be amplifying these biases in the HNQ list. This strikes me as unfortunate, since HNQs are specifically targeted at other people, i.e. ones who do not frequent our site, and whose maths education may not be so advanced. Elementary questions are therefore useful and important in the HNQ.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So, I think I would actually prefer looser standards to be applied when elementary questions make it on to the HNQ. I don't see any way of saving poor little "Discrete Math easy question", since the title really needs MathJax, but this is ideally what I would prefer.

Comment: @Theo: Again, this is ***not*** and ***never has been*** about elementarity. This is about proper exposition, and above that, proper titles. Clear and informative. I will not, and would not, like to see a question titled "Easy combinatorics proof, please help!" in the HNQ, and I don't believe anyone would either, except perhaps the people involved in that thread. We have so much terrible quality, I'd like to signal to the SE denizens that we also have *good* quality content, and that starts with titles.

Comment: @Asaf I understand. I do believe that you, and the rest of the mods, have no issues with elementary questions. However, due to the nature of the rules, I worry that elementarity accidentally falls by the wayside. I do acknowledge the issue about broadcasting a lack of quality, and I don't really have solutions, just two problems.

Comment: @Theo: It is unfortunate, yes. But I don't see the point you're trying to make. Should we let elementary questions have what is tantamount to garbage titles, just because they are elementary? How is this helpful? Why would anyone on the SE click on a question titled "Discrete math Easy question"? Sorry. I don't buy that ticket. You're currently worried that in the process of making a hamburger, the cow will die. And as unfortunate as that is, it is part of the making of a hamburger.

Comment: @Asaf In my opinion? I think we should always fix titles if possible, including adding Latex, thus probably removing them from the HNQ. If titles are not really possible to fix, I'd prefer that it didn't disqualify the question from remaining on the HNQ. It's not that I like clickbait (and I'm fine with replacing deliberate clickbait with a more prosaic title), but in such circumstances, I'd prefer the questions stay. As for why someone would click on questions with such titles, I'd simply respond that it's not our job to worry about that. Some people certainly must have clicked on it!

Comment: @Asaf My point is that the HNQ allows for outreach, which for reasons I haven't gone into in depth yet, I think is actually very important. Part of the HNQ's ability to do this is delivering questions that other people, who are not necessarily mathematically oriented, find interesting. Elementary questions are a part of this. Again, I'm not pretending the other issues don't exist, but that's why I would be in favour, in principle, of preserving elementary questions in the HNQ as best we reasonably can.

Comment: @Theo: As I repeatedly say. In the smashing majority of the cases, the titles can be fixed and perhaps I just don't have time at the moment to do it myself (when we consider elementary questions). I will, and I repeat that again, will oppose fiercely, any action to let "lazy titles" on the HNQ. I don't know if this is the point where we're talking past each other, or if this is the part where we already agreed. But you seem to insist on something very theoretical, that I don't even believe exists in a quantity larger than, say, one question per year. And that is *not* the one question [...]

Comment: [...] that will make the rest of SE suddenly decide that they like mathematics, if they didn't already like it before. So pretty please, with sugar on top, let's move on from some theoretical scenario, to realistic ones. The overwhelming majority of "elementary questions" **should** have $\rm\LaTeX$ in their titles. Therefore, the overwhelming majority of elementary questions should not be on the HNQ list. Furthermore, when they don't have $\rm\LaTeX$ in the title, their title tend to be awful. I am not going to let that stay on the HNQ if I have the power to fix that.

Comment: OK then, let's talk reality. In reality, regardless of what any of us decide, the decision of whether to bump a question off the HNQ is rarely going to perfectly fit any mould that we come up with. Ultimately, this is going to be a judgement made by a moderator (historically, you) in a small amount of time. By speaking theoretically, I was hoping (through wider participation than we've seen) to gauge the community's values on this matter, and hope that this, in some way, shapes your quick decision-making.

Comment: @Asaf But look, I'm about ready to give in. Few others apart from me seem to care about the HNQ at all (you seem to be one of the few, judging by the work you've put in pruning it), if participation in the discussion is any evidence. I'm about 85% happy with your current decisions on the subject, and that's a fairly comfortable level.

Comment: Theo, there is a problem with this approach. We had a lot of problems in the past discussion lack of context, since people agreed on "theoretical points" that were obvious, but not on the practical common cases. I find discussions about theory to be less conducive to results. This should be a more empirical approach. I am open to criticism regarding certain decisions about HNQ, and I admit that sometimes I make mistakes in my pruning. Nevertheless, talking about some theoretical elementary question that is well-posed and well-titled and yet without $\rm\LaTeX$, that's not helpful right now.

Comment: I did not yet catch up on everything that was said but one point (maybe already made): the hotness formula is for all I know quite sensitive to multiple answers and answers arriving quickly. Thus it favors a the type of questions that tend to get multiple answers quickly, which is also a source of bias and arguably towards the elementary part of the spectrum. I'll collect my thoughts and try to formulate an answer later but wanted to interject this.

Comment: Allow me to point out, since you're referring to Catija's post, that she very clearly writes that *users* should, if they see content on HNQ list, *"If the title seems click-baity or doesn't adequately describe the question, edit it!"*, so in reality, I shouldn't be pruning all these questions since the community should have been editing them to have adequate titles...

Comment: I downvoted this answer. While I agree that the topic should be discussed more widely, I simply disagree utterly with the general sentiment that HNQs should serve the function of reaching out to people not so interested in math. IMO the site is for *math enthusiasts at all levels, and professionals in related fields*. And inviting more dimwits asking for somebody to do their homework is diametrically opposite to that. The type of HNQs that moderators have voted out would attract exactly the type of users I don't want us to attract (and dispel the kind of users we should try and attract).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen (Rant incoming.) That is precisely the attitude that I'm opposed to, not just here, but in the wider mathematical community. Even without explicitly calling them dimwits, I don't think we gain anything good by trying to convince people that this site (or maths in general) isn't for them. It's incredibly elitist, needlessly personal, and just harmful to mathematics in general. Answerers are providing a service. It's OK for that service to not include providing ready-made solutions to homework. But so many people here don't just enforce policy, they actively profile the askers...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen They search for clues in the question to support their prejudices, and then deny them service based on personal judgements about their character. This is exactly the behaviour that makes maths anxiety worse, where a bunch of really intelligent people interact with you for a tiny amount of time, then dismiss you and any future you would have with mathematics! We are a big site for mathematics help (I'm guessing the biggest?). We help with maths at all levels. If we can't act with courtesy and respect to the wider community, then god help us all!

Comment: I admit that *dimwit* was out of line. And, having taught college students for 30 years, I know not to stoke people's math anxieties *in real life*. But, *this site* should, IMO, not be ashamed to show a front of ... *healthy eliticism*. If that means that we have 70% less people participating, that's fine. I don't see this as *a help site*. Rather a repository of polished Q&As

Comment: I guess we also avoid profiling *people* as homework dumpers. OTOH we can easily spot *questions* that are nothing but attempts to outsource HW. It is sad that some students end up on courses out of their depth, but doing their homework for them does not help them, when the real difficulties are caused by the holes in their background. AND THIS SITE DOES NOT WORK WELL IN FILLING IN THOSE HOLES. That takes time and dialogue with a teacher, which is what such askers should be instructed to do rather than try to cover these holes with the bandaids of copy/pastable solutions.

Comment: @Jyrki I don't believe we can spot said "homework dumpers". We can usually spot PSQs well enough. Dumping or outsourcing homework is a property of the person bringing the question to us, not the question itself. Again, you are profiling the person there, trying to infer a personal motivation from their interaction with the site. I don't think this inference is valid either. I think plenty of people who want to deepen their understanding of the material come here and post PSQs (with zero context). I'm not saying the behaviour should be encouraged, but I think that's indeed what happens.

Comment: @Jyrki But, moreover, even the inference "They may not be intending to dump homework on us, therefore we shouldn't necessarily shun them" makes me feel icky. I think their intentions **should not factor into our decision-making** at all. I agree that our service should be to help people learn to do maths better for themselves, and we should offer this regardless of who engages us (whether that's what they truly want or not).

Comment: A fundamental difference of opinions seems to be that IMO such questions should simply not be served. So if pruning some HNQs stops giving the impression that certain question would be welcome, that is net plus.

Comment: In the early years of the site there was a useful close reason *too localized*. Intending to be used, when a question and its answers would help a single person only. For some reason I cannot comprehend SE decided to abolish that close reason. The PSQ close reason is, in a sense, the less than ideal descendant of that. It would be IMO more honest to return to using too localized, for that  would better describe what the real problem with these questions is. But, sorry, I'm drifting away from the theme of this thread.

Answer (score 10):

Okay. I have a few minutes to spare. So I can write an answer to explain my approach to this, which is mainly on the table, seeing how I account for the majority of uses of this feature across the entire network (to the best of my knowledge).

---

I don't like clickbait. Or at least in most cases, I have a strong dislike to clickbait (I will admit to having written clickbaity titles before). Why is this relevant?

Well, seeing how any $\rm\LaTeX$ in the title of a question immediately excludes it from the HNQ, it means that in order to get a question on HNQ to begin with, it needs to have a title that has no $\rm\LaTeX$ in it.

Why is that an issue? Well, because it's a mathematics Q&A, and a lot of the questions *should* have titles that involve mathematical symbols. This means that a lot of the time, questions that end up on the HNQ list have one of three types of titles:

1. Lazy titles (which may or may not stem from laziness), for example "Simple integral question" or "Help with this proof".

   These titles are **terrible**. They tell you nothing about the question, and force you to click on the question just to get an idea of what the subject might even be. In 99.9999% of cases, such a question can be given a much better, clearer, and informative title. And in 99.9999% of *those* cases, such title would involve $\rm\LaTeX$.

   Why do I remove these from the HNQ? Well, because sometimes I just don't have the time to edit the title. Sometimes I do both. Sometimes I would still remove it, even if someone just edited the title. Why? Because we had users unroll titles in the past, just so they can have an answer on a question appearing on the HNQ list. And that, to be honest, sickens me.
2. Genuine titles, for example "Are there any new advances in computer-assisted algorithms for experimentally verifying Riemann Hypothesis?".

   This title is great. It's informative, it tells you what's up, where it is up, and why it is up. Great.

   In some cases, however, I would still remove such a question from the HNQ list. Why? Because maybe it's badly phrased. Maybe its body is just "My question is in the title (more characters)". Maybe something in the question just felt... lazy. Or maybe I acted too rashly.
3. Genuine clickbait titles. I don't have to provide examples of these, but this is somehow in the middle between the previous two categories, and it is often removed for the same reason as lazy titles, even if it's not entirely a lazy title.

---

Now. What about content? Well. When this feature was introduced, there was a fairly unanimous agreement between the moderators that questions on the HNQ should reflect content as we *want* it, rather as picked by an algorithm (which is designed, to the best of my knowledge, around how many answers were given, how quickly, and how many votes those answers received).

That means that lacking context, or lacking some crucial information, or just asking to verify a calculation. Those are all things we *don't want* to show the SE network as "good content".

It is unfortunate, yes. Most of the good content tend to have good titles, and those tend to have mathematical text in them, for a good reason. And that means that a lot of good content is missed out by the HNQ out of technical necessity.

But that is no excuse to fill it in with mediocre-at-best questions.

So let me address your five questions:

1. Maybe, depends on the question and depends on the answers.
2. Again, maybe. If there aren't enough "good answers", the question is not selected to begin with. So this scenario happens when a good question received a bunch of bad answers, or not-good-answers, that received enough votes nonetheless.
3. Usually yes, but this is more of a case-by-case basis.
4. Not because they are "homework", no. If they are lacking context, or somehow very uninteresting ("please verify my proof that sine integrates to cosine"), they should be removed. If it is a well-written homework question, and it has nice answers, there's no reason to exclude it just because it started from a homework assignment or a textbook.
5. It is bad enough that some people regard this site as a homework mill, and as a place with terrible questions. I don't see why we *shouldn't* remove questions that act to support this belief. If it was up to me to promote questions that I think are good, it would be my pleasure to suggest a handful per day. But it's not, and I can't.

---

Let me finish by saying that the natural state of a question is that it is *not* on the HNQ list. Most questions will never get there. So it is an extra privilege to be on the HNQ list. But it is not a privilege you get by having *actual good content*, rather it is a privilege you get due to hitting certain points for the algorithm. So it is not something you "work for", and if it is, then you're using the site wrong, to be honest.

This, to me, at least, is a justification to remove any and all questions from the HNQ list, which I would gladly do. But I understand that people would be happy to see mathematical questions across the network. I just try to make sure those are not homework-mill, low-effort, low-interest kind of questions.

Comment: "Well, because it's a mathematics Q&A, and a lot of the questions should have titles that involve mathematical symbols." — as a data point, looking at the top questions on mathoverflow this week, there are more TeX-free titles than titles using TeX. High points: "The Planck constant for Mathematicians", "Is the union of a chain of elementary embeddings elementary?", "Do Sobolev spaces contain nowhere differentiable functions?", "How rare are unholey permutations?" are all above 10 upvotes. I see no +10 questions on the week's top list that use TeX in their titles.

Comment: Broadening that to the month's top list barely changes this result; of the most highly upvoted questions on mathoverflow, the _research_ mathematics site, the overwhelming leaning is towards titles with no TeX in them whatsoever. I feel like this may be an unconscious bias coming to play.

Comment: I know what you mean, and I think that the culture of questions on MO is very different than here, for a good reason too. I also think that some of those highly upvoted questions are there *because* they had no LaTeX in the title and made it to the HNQ list. So you have shown correlation, yes, but it's more complicated than just that.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki As another (more quantitative) data point, about 22% of the latest 100 Mathoverflow questions have MathJax in their title.

Comment: "I don't have to provide examples of these" -- Why not?