# Mod removing questions out of HNQ

Tags: discussion, moderators, hot-questions-list

It has been observation as of late that moderator Asaf Karagila has been removing quite a bit of questions from HNQ. What is the basis for removal? and, under what circumstances is a moderator removing questions of HNQ justified?

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list) for some previous discussion.

Comment: Hmm [can't see how the removal of this question from HNQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502884/why-is-the-lebesgue-integral-defined-through-integrals-of-simple-functions) was justified based on that

Comment: I'm not taking a position, just letting you know about previous discussion.

Comment: @SouravGhosh That is a particularly bad post to be brought up as "evidence". I seem to have downvoted it back in the day. Also, it is ten years old. Nowadays it would be deleted. In my opinion it should have been deleted back in the day, but it is that kind of clickbait questions that raked in a lot of upvotes from nincompoops passing by.

Comment: "quite a bit of questions" means **7353** questions from 2019-03-13 until today according to this public [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/edit/1624845). Basically, Moderator Asaf Karagila has removed almost every single math question from HNQ.

Comment: Bruh moment extreme @user1046533

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational: that crucial context can be added to your post. But I will leave it to your own decision.

Comment: Regarding the previous discussion (which I initiated back in the day), I just want to point out that there wasn't a lot of active participation by the community in that discussion. The ability for mods to kill HNQs was relatively new, and I got the impression that: a) nobody cared as much about the issue as myself and Asaf, and b), a vague majority of meta users seemed to lean tend towards Asaf's position over mine. People seemed to care more by the time [this proposal](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/) rolled around. It might be a good time for a new discussion?

Comment: @TheoBendit: It seems to me that it is because no ordinary users can (can they?) affect HNQs due to the imbalanced power of moderators that makes not many wishes to participate in the discussion.

Comment: @user1046533 Ordinary users can, and sometimes do. Having MathJax in the title of a question automatically kicks a question from the HNQ, and though I lost the example, I did find an example of someone using this to remove a HNQ (I think it was `${}$` appended to a title). SEDE enquiries [found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34852/why-wasnt-this-question-removed-automatically-from-the-hnq-list) showed that this was rare behaviour though. Either way, the discussion was supposed to gather input from the community to generate a policy that mods would then try to stick to.

Comment: There are some very good questions in that SEDE query, exactly the types I'd like to be showing the rest of the world about MSE. The top two in this list are [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507001) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4506921), two very decent questions that deserve an audience of their own. There ought to be more community vetting of the HNQ. It's really unfortunate that under current circumstances, either the mods or the script has most of the control. It'd also give us an opportunity to sound out advanced excellent answers, which don't get attention.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: I'm terribly sorry, but no question with a title "About the definition of X" is good enough for the HNQ. Pay closer attention and improve the titles as things come into the HNQ to make them worth the effort, and it won't be removed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You needn't be terribly sorry about it, and I agree with you on the titling issue. Perhaps, instead of complaining like I did above, I will instead try and make sure the next post I see in the HNQ is edited to have a the right tags and a better title, if I think its content is good enough for the HNQ. As far as this issue is concerned, I can be proactive, so I will be.

Comment: I think I stand with Sarveshs original stance. Should the criteria of staying on HNQ list be the exterior packaging or the actual meat of the question?

Comment: I've implemented the suggestions of Asaf on four questions. More specifically, I edited the titles of three of them, pushing one out of the queue because the best title involved MathJax. There is another question, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507987) that I felt needed no editing. While a moderator may have some form of ultimate control (rightly so), I believe that we can have a more constructive conversation once we are doing our bit : making sure that every existing post in the HNQ is improved by us. Let's do this together.

Comment: There is something rather unfortunate I noticed in this process. While I did change the title of those questions, their titles *as written on the HNQ bar did not change*. [The title of this still reads "Simplification of a complex fraction"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507968) but when you click on it, you'll probably see a different title.  I think the HNQ's label will change after some time.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: The change to the HNQ takes a few minutes to kick in.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the update.

Comment: Let me correct you, "hot meta posts" are only shown *in site*. And the fact is that when it got more exposure, people came and saw the post, and decided that they disagree with your stance or tone or maybe something else that only they know. These are mostly, if not only, site regulars. They are not users who browse, say, literature.SE and saw your question on the HNQ, popped by, decided to upvote, and left. No, these are *actual* members of this community. If I were you, I'd consider removing that weird complaint that you've edited in.

Comment: It wasn't a complaint in any form, it was just an observation. I am of high doubt if any literature . SE users have enough knowledge to judge and upvote say the group theory that sarvesh posted or the lebesgue integral question I posted. I haven't seen myself doing vice versa for offsite posts or can imagine others doing it @AsafKaragila ; but nonetheless I comply to remove it on the post

Comment: The title description is important (eg to save time), and even _more_ if it's going to represent the kind of questions on math.SE, in the HNQ. For example,  a _new_ user that sees that,  could give themselves an idea of what form of titles are ok; but eg "about the def. of x" isn't a descriptive title (and not because there wasn't enough space to type).

Answer (score 5):

I've explained most of the reasons that I normally apply [in the past](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list). But let me also add that if I see a user whose questions very consistently and very frequently end up on the HNQ, then I will default to assuming that the user is trying to game this system. If nothing else, it will make me more judicial when looking at their questions that do make it to the HNQ.

Of course, sometimes honest mistakes happen. I sometimes remove questions and instantly realise that I did not want to remove *that* question.

Comment: Shouldn't the default assumption be innocent until proven guilty?

Comment: "I will default to assuming that the user is trying to game this system" Because of the power of diamond moderators, you do not need to justify your assumption to anyone, do you? And nobody except the community moderators can effectively question such an assumption; but of course, maybe they don't care at all.

Comment: I feel extraordinarily conflicted reading that gaming the system part. Other than voter fraud, how could one possibly game a system,  if any question can only be democratically voted up? Or, are you saying the site should be a mix of democracy + some curators who filter the items which are voted up. But wouldn't that sort of be hypocritical in some sense because you got voted up to become a mod yourself..?

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational a question in the HNQ tends to get upvotes from people who see it there and visit it.  Rightly or wrongly, that's the trend.  So if you could write questions that appeal to the HNQ algorithm, you could get a lot of (possibly unjustified) upvotes.  And since reputation is something that appeals to very many people on StackExchange sites, there's a motivation for it.  But, since the details of the algorithm are not made public, if you were to keep appearing in there, you would appear to have gamed the system....

Comment: Labelling votes as justified or unjustified is beyond the scope of the site as far as I understand. I remember some users mentioning in a few previous posts ago that there should be no justification for downvotes, and one can throw if they don't like... but for upvote, it needs approval of external agent to be attracted..? So, it seems to me ,  that the site users have come to a conclusion that the universal suffrage democracy doesn't work, and even voting must be vetted.

Comment: @postmortes IMO, these are highly subjective and speculative decisions. Unless there's strong evidence to suggest malpractice, I find it inappropriate to remove questions from the HNQ on a whim.

Comment: @BeKind that's nice.  I was explaining how the HNQ can attract upvotes to a question, not taking sides.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational all votes, up or down, have a justification in the mind of the vote-caster.  The only thing StackExchange (in general) has said along those lines is that up- and down-voters are not *required* to justify themselves.

Comment: @postmortes: We actually do know something about that algorithm. It is public knowledge that you need to get some answers fast enough, with some votes, and be aged at least 8 hours. In the case of this site, it also requires that the title will not have any MathJax. It isn't very hard to write questions like that. And when certain names appear more often than others, it does raise a suspicion that some kind of gaming is being done.

Comment: I also don't understand why people are so riled up. If you are not gaming the system, then the votes don't matter, then being on the HNQ doesn't matter.

Comment: Mods should curate the HNQ, like everything else, in the interest of making the site better. People do not have some constitutional right to seek reputation or a spot on the HNQ list.

Comment: Many of the sites policies like EOQS are not  in the site's default "Constitution" . It's a question of how much power the moderator should be allowed to swing around. @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: It is unclear what exactly the issue of "gaming the system" is when a question appears on HNQ, and how it adversely affects the site.

Comment: Well, moderators do have this power to "swing around" by virtue of that being the Stack Exchange system. If you don't like it, your escalation is to complain to the company through the CMs, or lobby against this power being available, or use a different system.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational you are clearly not familiar with the HNQ effect. The majority of users who visit a HNQ through the list do not have the capability of downvoting the question, but they can upvote it. This leads to a systematic bias in favour of gaining upvotes, which prolong the HNQ status, which leads to further votes, in a vicious cycle. This fact is well-known to users who hunt rep and badges and the 'glory' of getting their Q&A in front of bigger audience, regardless how poorly they actually represent the community (or how they represent the poorly community).

Comment: By your logic, if a mod started randomly banning people on their whim, that'd be justified too. Since they have the power , they can do whatever with it .

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational: No, by that logic, if a mod started banning random people on a whim, you can complain to the SE Community Managers, which will investigate the matter, as the "random" might not be random at all, and the "whim" might not be as whimsical as you see it, from your side of the terrace. And if the SE people find that the moderator is not conducting themselves properly, they will correct the problem and issue some punishment as they see fit.

Comment: @Nij: Not to mention that a lot of utterly incorrect answers get tons of upvotes from the HNQ drive-by voters who know zilch about proper mathematics. HNQ creates not only a bias towards upvotes, but also a bias towards junk promotion.

Comment: If you refer one to go to SE CMS for elevating a complaint, it says to me that once elected, there isn't much room for discussion of the actions/behaviors of a moderator in the community itself. It is to some level ironic, because moderators are community elected. @AsafKaragila

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational - Many people are able to discuss moderators' actions, both with the community and the moderators.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational: Don't twist my words. You were talking about a moderator suspending people on a whim. I gave you the oversight in that case. Moderators do not discuss suspension of users in public.

Comment: I think I met the Asaf fate with my first question and top question...